# Segmentation Fault Assembly debug

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

The following code has an errors which will probably result in a segmentation fault. Describe the problem. Why would it segfault? What is the fix?

```
  main: 
   call do_stuff 
   ret
  do_stuff: 
  push ebp 
  mov ebp, esp

  mov eax, 10 
  mov ebx, 20 
  mov ecx, 30 
  mov edx, 40 
  mov ebp, 50

  add eax, ebx 
  add eax, ecx 
  add eax, edx 
  add eax, ebp

  mov esp, ebp 
  pop ebp re
```

Comment: `mov ebp, 50` overwrites EBP with the value of an address (50) which is a bogus memory address. Eventually will reach `mov esp, ebp` and EBP will be copied to ESP which will have the result of screwing up the stack and then the the POP EBP will segfault trying to read memory you likely don't have read access to..

Comment: You also have another bug which probably *won't* lead to a segfault, but is still a bug:  `mov ebx, 20` clobbers EBX, which is a call-preserved register in all the normal calling conventions.  But most CRT startup routines (which call `main`) don't crash if EBX is clobbered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is stack handling. You are first writing the address of the stack pointer (esp) to the frame pointer (ebp), then you change ebp and move it back to esp, which causes the program to crash. Your code should be rewritten as follows:

```
do_stuff: 
  push ebp 
  mov ebp, esp ; for correct debugging

  mov eax, 10 

  add eax, 20 
  add eax, 30 
  add eax, 40 
  add eax, 50

  mov esp, ebp ; refresh stack pointer if it was changed
  pop ebp ; get pointer to previous frame
  ret ; the result will be stored in eax
```

Comment: Also, importantly, the default calling convention forbids you to use ebx. If you use it, you will also get a segfault.